# Search Results - prioritize order by related field

Tags: relations, search

I've got search working as expected on this site with the following code:

```
      {% set params = {
        section: 'inventions',
        limit: 10
      } %}

      {% if searchQueryKeywords !="" and searchQueryKeywords != null and searchQueryKeywords !="null" %}
        {% set params = params | merge({
          search:'title:' ~ searchQueryKeywords ~ ' OR summary:' ~ searchQueryKeywords ~ ' OR applications:' ~ searchQueryKeywords ~ ' OR investigators:' ~
          searchQueryKeywords ~ ' OR dbd:' ~
          searchQueryKeywords ~ ' OR caseNumber:' ~ searchQueryKeywords,  })
        %}
      {% endif %}

      {#
      // get related category
      #}
      {% if searchCategory != null and searchCategory !="" %}
        {% set searchQueryCategory = craft.categories.group('researchAreas').slug(searchCategory).one() %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if searchQueryCategory is defined %}
        {% set params = params | merge ({
          relatedTo: [
            'and',
            { targetElement: searchQueryCategory }
          ]
        }) %}
      {% endif %}


      {# set the entries with all the search/fitering params #}
          {% set entries = craft.entries(params) %}
```

However I now need to prioritize results to show entries that match the DBD entries field at the top. The DBD field is a relationship to a staff channel.

If I search for **Grant** how can I ensure that results for Grant appear at the top?